# How to add active css class to menu item?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

https://www.bootply.com/XzK3zrPhJJ

In this example, why is the `Home` button not marked red?

```css
.navbar a:hover,
.navbar a:focus,
.navbar a:active {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <div class="nav navbar-nav">
      <a href="/index.php" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Links</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Just a typo: `a.active` instead of/in addition to `a:active`.

Answer (score 2):

You shoud use not `a:active` but `a.active`

`:after` is a pseudo class. But you want to select `a` tags which **also has** `.active` class.

```css
.navbar a:hover,
.navbar a:focus,
.navbar a.active {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <div class="nav navbar-nav">
      <a href="/index.php" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Links</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the css [Class selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)

> The CSS class selector matches elements based on the contents of their
>   class attribute.

```css
.navbar a.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <div class="nav navbar-nav">
      <a href="/index.php" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Links</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

keep in mind that [The :hover CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)

> The :hover CSS pseudo-class matches when the user interacts with an
>   element with a pointing device, but does not necessarily activate it.
>   It is generally triggered when the user hovers over an element with
>   the cursor (mouse pointer).

and avoid `!important` you can read more about [!important_exception here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception)

Answer (score 0):

Why is it not active, but with active **CLASS**

instead of `a:active` use `.active` to reference, in this case you can also read more about the selector [HERE](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/active/)

Answer (score -1):

I think, it should be like this:

```
navbar a:hover {
color:red;
font-weight:bolder;
text-decoration:underline;
}
```